# Cookie based 4 day timer and then redirect Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies

I am trying to create a Cookie based redirection that takes someone to a new page once 4 days are passed.

I am expecting my site visitors to visit the promo offer page at least 7 times in the first 10 days so I need to make sure that the Cookie is generated for at least 30 days and the timer starts dynamically on their first visit.

Right now I only have this code and looking to get some help!

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
if (getCookie('cookiesSet') == "") {
setCookie('cookiesSet', 'yes', 365);
setCookie('passed4days', 'no', 4); 
} else if (getCookie('passed4days') == '')
window.location = 'www.facebook.com';
});

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
var c = ca[i];
while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
c = c.substring(1);
}
if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
}
}
return "";
}
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever check the expiration date of your 4-day cookie against the current date.  That would be a good next step.

Answer (score 0):

Snippet style as expected:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var firstVisitTime = getCookie('firstVisitTime')
  if (firstVisitTime != '') {
    var soManyDays = ((new Date()).getTime() - firstVisitTime) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    if (soManyDays > 4) window.location = 'www.stackoverflow.com'
    else if (soManyDays > 24) console.log('I should remember you')
  } else setCookie('firstVisitTime', (new Date()).getTime(), 366)
})
```